# Get single elements from Firestore Document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get single items from my Document in Firebase?

[image: Firestore DB]

I can get all elements with this code:

```
 let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String
        let docRef = firebaseDB.collection("user").document(key)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:))
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
```

I only wish to get the name and phone number. How can I filter my result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FirebaseFirestore has a handy way of caching single documents:

First, you need to specify the document by it's ID:

```
let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as? String ?? "Null" // Unique user key
let docRef = db.collection("user").document(key)
```

Get the document:

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
     if let document = document, document.exists {
         let docData = document.data()
         // Do something with doc data
      } else {
         print("Document does not exist")

      }
}
```

Access the doc data:

```
 let status = docData!["phone"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: I have no problem reading all of the data. But I only wish to access the Phone & Name and assign the contents to a label

Comment: yes, if I want to access from the another fields, how can do it? this isn't correct answer.

Comment: @ErkamKUCET Inside the if let statement, Hello? downvoting won't answer your question, you're free to ask another question, and when you downvote, have the decency to explain what's wrong.

Comment: @excitedmicrobe yes I see but why did you downvoting to my comment? :) no problem. Okay, I'm sorry for this because I got it wrong. I'm correcting.